How to get an intuitive viewpoint towards Bayes theorem
At the time of shuffling 52 playing cards, 5 cards are dropped accidentally. If it is known that 2 of 5 cards are red, find probability that all dropped cards are red cards.
I cannot seem to understand as to why we need to use Bayes theorem in this. The solution explains it as 5R/(2R + 3R + 4R + 5R).
I'm finding Bayes theorem very non-intuitive in such questions.

Consider the reduced sample space given by the information

See also conditional probability, specifically $~\displaystyle p(A|B) = \frac{p(A,B)}{p(B)}.~$  Here, $~B~$ is the event that at least two of the $~5~$ cards are red, and $~A~$ is the event that all $~5~$ cards are red.  Note that for this particular problem, $~p(A,B) = p(A).$
